# how do i make a roblox character move towards where it is looking at?

Tags: roblox

I can't find anything that can help me with this, and even tried to get answers from people on a discord server, but was still unable to find how to do this. If you find the answer, please provide the code, and where to put it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of research and found a couple of things that might help you.
First, there is a roblox scripting forum that might be a bit more helpful for you
[here.](https://scriptinghelpers.org/)

Second, you'll need to do two things.

a) get the cameraAngleX and cameraAngleY

b) pass those two the humanoid:move function [Link to docs](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Humanoid/Move)

You would then call the humanoid:move function however many times a second you want, which would move the player in the desired direction.

Comment: hold on, you said to get the camerAngle Y twice. is this intentional? second, how do i even get the camera angles?

Comment: It's part of the inputobject https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/InputObject. This is all in the roblox docs. If you have done any object oriented programming with a c language or java this should be pretty straightforward. If you haven't I would recommend learning one. https://nostarch.com has some great books on the subject. If that answers your question please accept my answer.